# Работа со временем в Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Столкнулась с проблемой анализа датасета. В колонке с датой представлена дата и время в формате `2018-09-01 00:00:05.2690`. Мне надо отсортировать прибытие по определённому времени (напр. с 9 до 11).

Подскажите, с помощью какой функции библиотеки Pandas или иной библиотеки я могу это сделать?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Приведите пример. Вы хотите только по времени сортировать или и по дате тоже? Вообще есть функция sort_values, которая позволяет сортировать DataFrame по одной или нескольким колонкам.

Comment: Если вам надо сортировать не по значению колонки, а по какой-то функции от содержания колонки, то проще всего сделать дополнительную колонку, в которую посчитать нужное для сортировки значение, а потом отсортировать с помощью sort_values по этой колонке.

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201809-citibike-tripdata.csv.zip

Comment: именно по времени

Comment: Под «отсортировать» вы подразумеваете отфильтровать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если речь в вопросе идёт о фильтрации данных по времени, то это можно сделать так:

сначала убедитесь что столбец содержащий дату и время имеет тип данных datetime64, если это строки (тип данных: object), то этот столбец надо преобразовать в тип datetime:

```
df[”dt_col_name”] = pd.to_datetime(df[”dt_col_name”], errors=“coerce”)
```

Теперь можно фильтровать, воспользовавшись [Series.between()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
res = df.loc[df[”dt_col_name”].dt.hour.between(9, 11)]
```